# Can a magnetic case harm my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, case

I am thinking about buying a magnetic iPhone 4S case but I'm not sure whether it's safe. Can this magnetic case be harmful for the inner parts of my iPhone 4S? The case looks exactly like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008XXOFA2):

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage on a 4S is Flash-based, not magnetic-media-based, which would be my prime concern in a scenario like this—so you're safe there.  I'm not aware of any other components in the 4S that would be affected by a magnetic case.  I have personally carried my own 4S in various magnetic cases for about a year now with no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will have some issues with the magnetometer, inside Compass app or navigation apps.